# Multiple choice question on $\limsup x_n$ and $\liminf$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $x_n = \left(1−\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin(\frac{nπ}{3})$ for $n \ge 1$. Denote $l=\liminf x_n$ and $s=\limsup x_n$. Then

1. $l \ge -\sqrt{3}/2$
2. $s \le \sqrt{3}/2$
3. $l \ge -1/2$
4. $s \le 1/2$

I am not able to find the limit here, please help with this.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Is l=-√3/2 and s=√3/2, n odd and n even cases

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: How to prove this

Comment: For $\limsup$ for example, you can show that each term is greater than $-\sqrt{3}/2$, and then exhibit a subsequence that converges to  $-\sqrt{3}/2$.